# onbeforeunload event with apache wicket

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, wicket

I've a problem with the JavaScript event `onbeforeunload` in Apache Wicket.

What I want to do: I've a variable which tells me if data has changed. Now I want to open the JavaScript confirm dialog (`confirm("my text");`) to ask if the user is sure that he is losing his changes.
This dialog should only pop up, if something has changed.

Does anyone knows how the behavior is working correctly?

I tried this:

```
add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onbeforeunload") {

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.prependJavaScript("confirm('my dialog');");
    }
});
```

What it does: I get now two dialogs. The first one is a dialog with the text "false" in it. The second one is my real dialog.

Does anyone has experience with this event?

Answer (score 3):

Michael, I see you've a wrong preposition how onbeforeunload works and where is you AjaxEventBehavior.

The AjaxEventBehavior adds the listener on a javascript event. You can use one of well known elements' events like 'onclick', 'onchange' etc. The second way is to use your own event, e.g. 'myevent' and trigger it from a javascript. Both of those cases mean you add the AjaxEventBehavior onto an HTML element like 'DIV', 'A', etc.

However the event 'onbeforeunload' is really another case because it is an event defined by window, so it is 'window.onbeforeunload'.

One of the most easy way is to create an HTML element and add there a custom event. Then add a javascript to your head section of the page that just add the trigger of the previously defined event to the onbeforeunload.

**EXAMPLE:**

***Wicket 1.6***

Markup

```
<div wicket:id="myElement">[just a placeholder tag]</div>
```

Code Example:

```
static String CUSTOM_EVENT_NAME = "myElementEvent";

add(new WebMarkupContainer("myElement") 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) 
    {
        super.renderHead(response);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.append("$(window).bind('onbeforeunload', function() { $('#");
        sw.append(getMakupId());
        sw.append("').trigger('");
        sw.append(CUSTOM_EVENT_NAME);
        sw.append("'); });");
        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(sw.toString()));
    }

}
.setOutputMarkupId(true)
.add(
    new AjaxEventBehavior(CUSTOM_EVENT_NAME) 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) 
        {
        // your code
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: How would you do this in wicket 1.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

With wicket 1.3.7 i solved it like this:

```
protected static final String EVENT_ON_UNLOAD = "onunload"; //Be shure eventname is lowercase only

body = new WebMarkupContainer("_body_")
{
    @Override
    public void renderHead(HtmlHeaderContainer container)
    {
        super.renderHead(container);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.append("window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) { $('#");
        sw.append(body.getMarkupId());
        sw.append("').trigger('");
        sw.append(EVENT_ON_UNLOAD);
        sw.append("'); });");

        String javascript = sw.toString();
        IHeaderResponse response = container.getHeaderResponse();
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(javascript);
    }
};
body.setOutputMarkupId(true);
body.add(new AjaxEventBehavior(EVENT_ON_UNLOAD)
{
    protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        // your Code
    }
});
add(body);
```

I added it to the basepage which simplified looks like this

```html
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>

  <body wicket:id="_body_">
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```